# ModuleNotFoundError jsonrpc

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a project in python 3.9 and when I compile, I get this error :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jsonrpc'
```

I don't know what to do to fix this error, I already used the following command:

```
pip3 install jsonrpc
```

if anyone knows why it doesn't work, I'm looking for solutions

I would like to thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: Did you try it with a `-` between `json` and `rpc`?
Like this: `pip3 install json-rpc`

Comment: yes i tried and it doesn't work either....